# How to x:bind collection of collections?

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to show collection of collections via FlipView elements and i have a trouble with proper binding settings. I have to set x:DataType for DataTemplate element, but i can't find any way to set List type there.

Here is my Example. It's just a prototype project, so i don't use MVVM for make it simpler:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public List<List<CustomItems>> ItemList;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ItemList = new List<List<CustomItems>>();

        List<CustomItems> tlist = new List<CustomItems>();
        tlist.Add(new CustomItems { title = "test1", text = "first text", url = new Uri("http://microsoft.com") });
        ItemList.Add(tlist);

        tlist = new List<CustomItems>();
        tlist.Add(new CustomItems { title = "test2", text = "second text", url = new Uri("http://google.com") });
        tlist.Add(new CustomItems { title = "test2-1", text = "second 1 text", url = new Uri("http://gmail.google.com") });
        tlist.Add(new CustomItems { title = "test2-2", text = "second 2 text", url = new Uri("http://drive.google.com") });
        ItemList.Add(tlist);

        tlist = new List<CustomItems>();
        tlist.Add(new CustomItems { title = "test3", text = "third text", url = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com") });
        ItemList.Add(tlist);
```

My xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="grids.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:grids"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Width="850" Height="600"
    xmlns:data="using:grids.Models"
    >

    <Grid Width="850" Height="600" >
        <FlipView x:Name="gridView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="850" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemList}">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="WHAT_SHOULD_BE_HERE?">
                    <FlipView ItemsSource="{x:Bind}">
                        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:CustomItems">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind title}"></TextBlock>
                                    <WebView Source="{x:Bind url}" Width="850" Height="400" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                    </FlipView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        </FlipView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Using x:Bind i have to set x:DataType, but as i've told i don't see any way to set List-type for first FlipView. I've tried to use separate xmlns pointed to System.Collections.Generic, but i can't use List from there. Somewhere i've seen advice to create own class inherited from List>, i've tried that too, xaml code-checking then allowed me to build the project, but i've got the runtime exception: "throw new global::System.ArgumentException("Incorrect type passed into template. Based on the x:DataType global::grids.Models.MyCollection was expected.");"
So can anybody explain me what is the proper way to do that?